# Can't finish php5-cli update

Tags: ubuntu, apt, php5

I get the following error after doing `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Setting up php5-cli (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6) ...
ucfr: Attempt from package php5-cli  to take /etc/php5/cli/php.ini away from package php5-fpm
ucfr: Aborting.
dpkg: error processing package php5-cli (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-readline:
 php5-readline depends on php5-cli (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6); however:
  Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-pear:
 php-pear depends on php5-cli; however:
  Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php-pear (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-cli
 php5-readline
 php-pear
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After that, I tried `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5`, all of them with the same error.

How can I fixed this?

Comment: Try removing `php5-fpm` first, using `dpkg -r php5-fpm`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve it, I had to remove the symlink in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` that points to `../fpm/php.ini`.

After that, all works as expected.

I found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196108&p=13088005#post13088005).

Comment: Well, that is irritating.

Comment: This resolved my issue as well.     sudo unlink php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue just now and this was the first result, and it didn't solve my issue, so I wanted to leave my solution here.  I found a bogus file that had been created due to improperly running php5enmod in 
/var/lib/php5/modules/registry
Once I removed the file from there that wasn't an actual php5 module everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/

apt-cache policy php5-cli

ls -l php5-cli.*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo rm -r php5-cli.*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This seems incoherent. What is accomplished by showing the policy (source) of the package? The repeated apt-get clean invocations make no sense. Likewise, screwing around with php5-cli package metadata can cause further problems - do you want to remove the maintainer scripts, empty the package file list, or? It hardly makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `deb.sury.org` developer Ondřej Surý does not want to fix it:

> You most likely symlinked the php.ini between the packages. That’s not supported.

[github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1473#issuecomment-713839096](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1473#issuecomment-713839096)

So I fixed it myself by patching `deb.sury.org` files in the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` folder.
I documented my solution for **PHP 7.4** here: [df.tips/t/1940/3](https://df.tips/t/1940/3)
For other PHP versions it is similar.